# npm does not install packages when behind proxy on LAN

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package

I am using latest node and latest npm version
I am using LAN of my college
Its proxy details is:
Address: `172.16.199.40`
Port: `8080`
i am running command to install an express app `npm i express`. It does not run for a minute or so and after that raises the following error

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.0.2.1:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

YES I am behind a proxy. I have tried all possible ways by seeing similar questions on this site to change it and then also it is not installing.
Please help

I tried to set using `npm set proxy 172.16.199.40:8080`
`npm set https-proxy 172.16.199.40:8080`

But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I am also using proxy for a lan server. My npm works fine. Here's how I fixed it.

Since your address and port are given I will be telling according to that only

```
npm config set proxy http://172.16.199.40:8080

npm config set https-proxy http://172.16.199.40:8080
```

I hope you would have seen your mistake. It was in not writing http:// before writing your address and port.
This will surely work